# javascript Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute deleteObj function:

```
<td class="tdDesign">
  <a onClick="javascript:deleteObj(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)">
    <img src="images/deleteSmaller.PNG">
  </a>
</td>
```

but i'm getting this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

What is wrong?

**edit:**  $row['id'] is a parameter from database

Comment: Is this on a page where PHP is actually running? + what is `$row['id']`?

Comment: $row['id'] is a parameter from database

Comment: you  are getting  this erro at  php  or js console?

Answer (score 2):

**First**

Make sure `<?php` is interpreted, as the `<` in the error message might actually refer to that. Also make sure you are not already using PHP to output the HTML code you mentioned in your example. If this is the case, you do not need another `<?php ?>` tag, but instead you have to make sure that `$row['id']` is treated as variable:

```
echo '<tag attribute="javascript:do(' . $row['id'] . ');">';
```

**Second**

Check whether the contents of `$row['id']` express valid javascript. Perhaps you want to output a string? Make sure that your result from `$row['id']` is contained in quotes (if it is not a valid expression, such as an integer or a regular expression).

Comment: Good point.  OP, use "View Source" on your browser to see what is actually being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is actually running!  Javascript is seeing `<?php echo $row['id'] ?>` when you meant it to see the content of row[id].

It might be caused by misconfiguration of the server, or something about the quotation marks that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `<` and `>` characters in an html/xml attribute using `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities like following:

```
<a onClick="javascript:deleteObj(&lt;?php echo $row['id'] ?`&gt;)">
```